# Trying to sort by string sheet number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a list by the document identifier in ascending order, (in which the order is BMC-9, CSR-9, MC-9, then LC-9) then by sheet number in which the order should go like the picture seen below. I have it where the code puts the document identifier in the order I want, but my sheet number is not in the order I would like.

I have already tried to record the order I want with a macro. I have also posted my existing code here.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub CableWiringSort()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range
    Dim wsSort As Worksheet
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vToSort As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(\d+)-?(\D*)" 'note that some do not have a hyphen
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    Dim J As Range

'input data to variant array
Set ws = Worksheets("TELECOM")

Dim strSearch As String

Call findlc

With ws
    vSrc = .Range(ActiveCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'create array of ColB, and Col C split into Numeric, Alpha & len(alpha) for column c
'cannot split column 2 on the hyphen since not all requiring a split contain a hyphen.

ReDim vToSort(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 7)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False 'or could be true
    .Pattern = sPat
End With
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        vToSort(I, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
            V = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "-")
        vToSort(I, 2) = V(0)
        vToSort(I, 3) = V(1)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vSrc(I, 2))
        vToSort(I, 4) = vSrc(I, 2)
        vToSort(I, 5) = MC(0).submatches(0)
        vToSort(I, 6) = MC(0).submatches(1)
        vToSort(I, 7) = Len(vToSort(I, 6))
Next I

'write to hidden sheet for sorting
Set wsSort = Worksheets.Add
With wsSort
    '.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Set r = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vToSort, 1), UBound(vToSort, 2))
    r.Value = vToSort
End With

'sort on the hidden sheet
wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(2) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:="BMC,CSR,MC,LC" _
        , DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(3) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(5) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(7) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wsSort.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(6) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wsSort.Sort
        .SetRange r
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'create results array with the needed columns
Dim vRes1 As Variant, vRes2 As Variant
Set r = Union(r.Columns(1), r.Columns(4))

vRes1 = r.Areas(1)
vRes2 = r.Areas(2)

'write back to the original sheet
'but offset for now for trouble shooting
Set r = Worksheets("TELECOM").Cells(1, 10).Resize(UBound(vRes1, 1), 2)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
With r
    .Columns(1).Value = vRes1
    .Columns(2).Value = vRes2
    .EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

'delete the hidden sheet
    .DisplayAlerts = False
        wsSort.Delete
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Call findlc
Call Last

With Sheets("TELECOM").Range("A14:F305")
            With .Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .FontStyle = "Regular"
                .Size = 9
            End With
            End With


End Sub
```

[image]

I would like to bring sheet 2 as part of the drawing series above F1 and below A4 (seen in picture) I want the order to go in numbers first, then letters. So, all the data above LC-900785 is correct. The order for the LC-900785 should be:

```
LC-900785   2
LC-900785   F1
LC-900785   F2
LC-900785   F4
LC-900785   L1
LC-900785   Z1
LC-900785   Z2
```

Comment: `Sortfields.Add2` has an option `DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers`. If that doesn‘t help, you need to extract parts of your column values into an additional column and sort by that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and I really test it, it works 100%, and with even blank rows I Hope help you.

[image]

Sub BtnOrdertwoCell_Click()

On Error Resume Next

Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Dim ColRowsCount As Integer

ColRowsCount = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Range("A2:A" & ColRowsCount, "B2:B" & ColRowsCount).Sort Key1:=Range("A2", "B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer. Perhaps you are answering the wrong question? Thanks for trying tho. :)

Comment: You are most welcome brother, but if you look well, you can notify that is the same idea you might asked for, order two columns grouping by also those two columns. You ONLY need to change the columns letters (B,C) instead of what I've done (A,B)  ^_^

Comment: It's not working. I need to sheets 8 and 8A to be together. Instead they are at opposite ends of the list. :/